# Can I reuse an Activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-state

I apologize in advance for my English, I'm developing my first app and I don't know how to proceed.
I have an activity that register a thing, I want to provide the option to modify that registration. I thought about reusing the register activity for doing that, I mean, when you click "modify" it opens the register activity with all its fields filled out and you can modify whatever you want (not with empty fields as a new register activity does), and then make a different query to update the record in the SQLite, etc.
I don't know how to capture that I'm calling that activity for doing another thing instead of registration. Is that possible? or should I create a new activity for doing that?

Thank you!!

Comment: It isn't much clear what you're asking but, you can pass a boolean variable in the `intent` to launch the activity to pass the reason for starting the activity and make the activity react accordingly.

Comment: Should I use flags for that ?

Comment: I meant something like: `intent.putExtra("for_registration", false)`...and then reading that data in your activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse it for example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
i.putExtra("id", someId);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

> Remember to call finish() to remove the activity from backstack so
>   when you press back you don't return to previous instance of the same
>   activity

Then use this to get the id for query:

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- Bundles, to pass data between activities.
- Static variables to access data from another class
- Pass data using bundles or use static variables and reuse your layout file from previous activity in another activity or change visibility of some views in the same activity